# http://example.com/portal/p/Logon/ not working after migration (Apache, php)

Tags: php, dynamic, migration, webserver, apache2

I have migrated a dynamic website (php, mysql) to a new host on a shared server plan.

The site is fully dynamic and has no fixed paths as such apart from the single entry point file "portal.php".  The site exists as path-info to portal.php and is created from templates in a mysql database. There is no /portal directory, for example.

The homepage loads fine, but not subpages.The pathinfo is returned correctly, but the webserver is not translating it I guess:

http://example.com/portal/p/Logon        =  Fails with 404 error
http://example.com/portal.php/p/Logon    = Works!

I have limited control over the apache server as the client has a basic, shared server plan.

I tried various options in a .htaccess file at the root of the website directory, but the best I could do was get an internal 500 error. At least I know the .htaccess is being read.

I'm hoping I can resolve this, otherwise I will have to migrate the site to a dedicated server instead.

Comment: Could it be, the folder portal has the wrong name? Accidentally renamed to portal.php

Comment: There isn't much diagnosis to go with that observation. The real error message lies in the error.log. Without more details this will go unanswered. VTC.

Comment: More content added. Unfortunately the error logs seem only to come daily and with no useful information yet. I have no control over the error log configuration, it appears to be a very basic plan.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution. I see now why my initial post lacked information :)

I read this guide:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

And after trial and error, the following worked with a .htaccess file placed at root (I modified a html5boilerplate .htaccess file):

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^portal/(.*) /portal.php/$1
RewriteRule ^portal$ /portal.php
```